# I cant add react-bootstrap to NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap-table

I cant use React-bootstrap to NextJS

I've added import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in _app.tsx and yarn add

Please help me, i'm newbie

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="me-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                                    Another action
                                </NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                                    Separated link
                                </NavDropdown.Item>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar> 
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have defined same named component which you have imported i.e. `Navbar`.

try the following code

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar as BNavbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <BNavbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                <Container>
                    <BNavbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                    <BNavbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <BNavbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="me-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                                    Another action
                                </NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                                    Separated link
                                </NavDropdown.Item>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </BNavbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </BNavbar> 
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```